# save json data via ajax with php

Tags: php, jquery, json

i have a json file and show the data as a list
with the input fields everything can be edited and if save is clicked, i want to override the json file with the new data

have the following markup

```
   <ul id="sortable">
      <li>
         <input class="jahr" type="number" value="2010" placeholder="Jahr">
         <input class="titel" type="text" value="testtitel" placeholder="Titel">
         <input class="delete" type="button" value="löschen">
     </li>
      <li>
         <input class="jahr" type="number" value="2012" placeholder="Jahr">
         <input class="titel" type="text" value="testtitel2" placeholder="Titel">
         <input class="delete" type="button" value="löschen">
     </li>
   </ul>
```

now i want to save the data in a json file, so i have the following jquery code

```
var erfolge = [];

$('#sortable').children().each( function(){
    erfolge.push({titel : $(this).find('.titel').val(), jahr: $(this).find('.jahr').val()});                
});

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
    url: "erfolge_speichern.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { json: erfolge }
});
```

and the php file looks like this:

```
<?
$json = $_POST['json'];

$file = fopen('../json/erfolge.json','w+');
fwrite($file, json_decode($json));
fclose($file);
?>
```

when i look at the post data with firebug it looks like this

```
json[0][jahr]   2010
json[0][titel]  testtitel
json[2][jahr]   2012
json[2][titel]  testtiel2
```

the json file is then empty

Thanks in advance!

Comment: echo the $json object individually and with json_decode and try to find out what it contains.

Comment: $json is an array, json_decode($json) is NULL

Comment: I had this same issue before. It's because PHP's `json_decode` function is very strict on how the json should be formatted. Try `echo $json`, and let us know what you get.

Comment: $_POST['json'] is an array, so instead of 

json_decode($json);

i used

json_encode($json);

now it works!
there is a problem with the special characters, but thats another story ...